# 'str' object is not callable, functions as args

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a program as an exercise to calculate the integral value from a to b with one of 2 mathematical functions. My function integrate should have f as the mathematical function to integrate.

```
from math import *

def g(x):
        return float(x) * float(x) + 3

def h(x):
    return math.cos(float(x) * float(x))

def integrate(f, a, b, n):
    H = (abs(float(a) - float(b)))/float(n)
    ans = 0
    xWaarde = a - H/2
    print xWaarde
    for k in range(1, n+1):
        xWaarde = xWaarde + H
        ans = ans + f(xWaarde) * H
    return ans

print 'available functions:'
print 'g(x) = x^2+3'
while True:
    print 'h(x) = cos(x^2)'
    aIn = float(raw_input('integral from a = '))
    bIn = float(raw_input('to b = '))
    nIn = int(raw_input('Number of subintervals: '))
    while True:
        funcIn = raw_input('Which function do you want to use? (g or h): ')
        if funcIn == 'g':
            integrate(g,aIn,bIn,nIn)
            break
        elif funcIn == 'h':
            integrate(h,aIn,bIn,nIn)
            break
        else:
            print 'This function is not available'


    print 'The definite integral is', integrate(funcIn, aIn, bIn, nIn)
    doorg = raw_input('Do you want to continue? (y or n): ')
    if doorg == 'n':
        break
    else:
        print
```

The full Traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nick van Stijn/Desktop/Python/Assignment 3.1.py", line 38, in <module>
    print 'The definite integral is', integrate(funcIn, aIn, bIn, nIn)
  File "C:/Users/Nick van Stijn/Desktop/Python/Assignment 3.1.py", line 16, in integrate
    ans = ans + f(xWaarde) * H
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

EDIT: SOLVED
I made a mistake by calling a function at a time I didn't have to call it at all.

Comment: For example `f == 'g'` at that point - that's just a single-character string, what do you expect calling it to do?

Comment: Just to be clear, the error is in `print 'The definite integral is', integrate(funcIn, aIn, bIn, nIn)`, not the original integration. `funcIn` is the string, not `g` or `h` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call `integrate` using the proper function, `f` or `g`, but then *discard* the result and instead call `integrate` *again* for the print, this time passing just the *name* of the function, `funcIn`.

Instead, you should just store the result in a variable, e.g., like this:

```
result = None
while result is None:
    funcIn = raw_input('Which function do you want to use? (g or h): ')
    if funcIn == 'g':
        result = integrate(g,aIn,bIn,nIn)
    elif funcIn == 'h':
        result = integrate(h,aIn,bIn,nIn)
    else:
        print 'This function is not available'

print 'The definite integral is', result
```

Also, you could use a `dict` to map function names to actual functions, instead of using a possibly large number of `if/elif/else`:

```
functions = {'h': h, 'g': g}
while result is None:
    funcIn = raw_input('Which function do you want to use? (g or h): ')
    if funcIn in functions:
        result = integrate(functions[funcIn],aIn,bIn,nIn)
    else:
        print 'This function is not available'
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually explains why the error is happening.

Comment: YES, thank you, it was a stupid mistake, the code i used was copied from a former excercise I did, the line with "print 'The definite integral is'" should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the textual name of the function in the form of a string, rather than a reference to the function object itself.  While there are hacky techniques to derive the function object from a string name, they can difficult to maintain and error-prone.  Since in python functions are objects like any other (so called "first-class" objects) they are not really named, only *references* to functions have names.

This is a good example where a dictionary comes in handy, particularly if you wish to add more functions later.  We can map a text key (what the user enters) to any python object, including a function:

```
from math import *

def g(x):
        return float(x) * float(x) + 3

def h(x):
    return math.cos(float(x) * float(x))

# Store references to the functions in a dictionary
# with the keys as the text name (the names need not match)
funcs = {'g': g, 'h': h}        #  <<<<  ADDED

def integrate(f, a, b, n):
    H = (abs(float(a) - float(b)))/float(n)
    ans = 0
    xWaarde = a - H/2
    print xWaarde
    for k in range(1, n+1):
        xWaarde = xWaarde + H
        ans = ans + f(xWaarde) * H
    return ans

print 'available functions:'
print 'g(x) = x^2+3'
while True:
    print 'h(x) = cos(x^2)'
    aIn = float(raw_input('integral from a = '))
    bIn = float(raw_input('to b = '))
    nIn = int(raw_input('Number of subintervals: '))
    while True:
        funcIn = raw_input('Which function do you want to use? (g or h): ')

        # THIS CODE CHANGED - note the simplification
        # we just test for membership of the dictionary
        if funcIn in funcs:
            integrate(funcs[funcIn],aIn,bIn,nIn)
            break
        else:
            print 'This function is not available'

    # THIS CODE CHANGED (note first argument to integrate)
    print 'The definite integral is', integrate(funcs[funcIn], aIn, bIn, nIn)
    doorg = raw_input('Do you want to continue? (y or n): ')
    if doorg == 'n':
        break
    else:
        print
```

Comment: While this fixes the OP's problem and introduces a better technique, a note that the line `print 'The definite integral is', integrate(funcs[funcIn], aIn, bIn, nIn)` was the thing that broke in the original code would be nice.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: fair comment.  I had not included it because the reason for the fault was already well explained.  My aim was only to show a better technique.